# What are some of the specific sources saying that Yitzchak’s central attribute is Gevurah or Din?

Tags: sources-mekorot

What are some of the specific sources saying that Yitzchak’s central attribute is Gevurah or Din?

I have heard and read this many times, but always in the abstract. Like:

“Chazal reveal the central attributes possessed by the Avos. The central trait of Avraham was chesed, the central trait of Yitzchak was gevurah, and the central trait of Yaakov was emes.”

I’d like to know where I might find some specific supportive texts. Is this found in one of the sifrei Zohar? If so, where (any links to specific Sefaria or related online texts would be great, if that exists).

Comment: Not a source that outright states that Yitzchak is Din, but there's an example of this aspect of Din with regards to Yitzchak in Shabbat 82b.

Comment: It's all over the Zohar, not even one specific reference. You probably can't go five blatt in the Zohar without a reference to Yitzchak/gevurah.

Comment: I don't have it in front of me but I believe there is a related discussion at the beginning of the Sod HaNachash by Rav Gikatilla. I'm sure there are many other sources. The idea is also discussed in Siftei Chein, who I'm sure brings sources.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, welcome to Mi Yodeya. Great to have you learning with us.

There are actually different sources that say this. One of these is, as you say, the [Zohar in parshas Vayeshev](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar,_Vayeshev.5.46).

> "He shall be exalted," means that (the Nukva shall be filled) from that facet of the light that is superior to all the lights, (i.e. Keter). "He shall be exalted" as in, "and therefore will He be exalted, that He may have mercy upon you" (Isaiah 30:18); "and extolled," on the side of Abraham, i.e. Chesed. "And be high," on the side of Isaac, i.e. Gevurah, while "very," on the side of Jacob, (is Tiferet). And although this has already been explained, all is one in the secret of wisdom.

See also [Me'or Einayim, parshas Toldos](https://www.sefaria.org/Me%27or_Einayim,_Toldot.20).

The Tiferes Shlomo, Rabbi Shlomo Hakohen Rabinowicz writes [(Tiferes Shlomo, Moadim, Shabbos HaGadol)](https://www.sefaria.org/Tiferet_Shlomo,_on_Festivals,_Shabbat_HaGadol.3):

> "Gevurah" corresponds to Isaac since he's connected with fear, which is associated wit strength.

Answer (score 0):

For a source from the Arizal, see [Shaar Hapesukim](https://www.sefaria.org/Sha%27ar_HaPesukim,_Parashat_Lech_Lecha.11) in the beginning of Lech Lecha. It's too long and abstruse for me to feel comfortable translating it here, but if you take a look at the link you can read about a page's worth of commentary discussing the sefiros associated with each of the Avos.

Comment: I think this counts as a link-only answer. If something is such a deep sod that it shouldn’t be translated, I also don’t think it’s a great answer to bring on an online forum

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I hear that. When it comes to Kabbalistic sources I do think there's often a fine line. Nonetheless, the answer is otherwise correct, so I'll leave it up for those who do want to click the link and examine the text for themselves.

Comment: And what if the link is broken somehow? That's why it is greatly appreciated to add in all relevant stuff, including text/translations etc..